# Joomla 3.1 add fields to user profile

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I want to add more fields to the user profiles, such as an image URL.
I want it to work just like this:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo "Your name is {$user->name}, your email is {$user->email}, and your username is 
{$user->username}";
```

In other words, i want to be able to do this:

```
$profilepicture = $user->image;
```

Is this possible? And how is it done?

Comment: are you wanting to show extra field for the user to fill in or do you already have that done and simply want to display the results?

Comment: @Lodder - I just got the extra field added, now I have problems displaying the results.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes It's possible
- It is done following the [Creating a profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own user plugin by cloning the current one and adding whatever fields you need to the xml.  Or you can just add another xml form to the current one but you'd have to modify the core to tell it when to use the fields.
Or just change one of the fields in the current form to a media field.